# seg fault when called from python, but runs normally from the command line

Tags: python, bash, googletest

I am writing a python script that is used for continuous integration and test that will be called by bitten.  Our unit tests use the google test framework.  Each software component has a bash script that runs configuration and other required services and runs the gtest executable.  The python script walks the repository looking for the bash scripts, and calls each script using the os.popen() command.

Python script (UnitTest.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import fnmatch
import sys
import subprocess

repository_location = '/home/actuv/workspace/eclipse/iccs/'
unit_test_script_name = 'RunUnitTests.sh'

def file_locator(repo, script_name):
    # Function for determining all unit test scripts
    test_location = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(repo):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, script_name):
            test_location.append(os.path.join(root))
    return test_location

def run_tests(test_locations, script_name):
    # Runs test scripts located at each test location
    for tests in test_locations:
        cmd = 'cd ' + tests + ';./' + script_name
        print 'Running Unit Test at: ' + tests
        os.popen(cmd)

################    MAIN    ################
# Find Test Locations
script_locations = file_locator(repository_location, unit_test_script_name)

# Run tests located at each location
run_tests(script_locations)

# End of tests
sys.exit(0)
```

Bash Script

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Running unit tests..."

# update the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include paths to our shared libraries

# start the test server

# Run the tests

# wait to allow all processes to end before terminating the server
sleep 10s
```

When I run the bash script manually from a terminal window, it runs fine.  When I have the python script call the bash script I get a segmentation fault on the TestSingleClient and TestMultiClientLA lines of the bash script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
os.popen(cmd)
```

with

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('./scriptname', shell = True, 
                       cwd = tests)
proc.communicate()
```

Comment: I initially had an issue that it couldn't find the script, but I realized that I needed to include the './' before the script name.

Comment: I also found that the stdout and stderr can cause significant issues when allowed to pipe to the bitten console.  I opened a temporary file (temp = open(temp, 'w') and added the stdout=temp and stderr=temp flags to the Popen call.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely check out [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.htm) module - specifically look at **subprocess.call()** convenience method.  I threw in a os.path check to make sure your tests directory exists too.

```
def run_tests(test_locations, script_name):
    # Runs test scripts located at each test location
    for tests in test_locations:
        #  Make sure tests directory exists and is a dir
        if os.path.isdir(tests):
            print 'Running Unit Test at: ' + tests
            subprocess.call(script_name, shell=True, cwd=tests)
```

Also - You're correct in you observations about stdout and stderr causing issues, especially when there's lots of data.  I use temp file(s) for stdout/stderr when there is a large or unknown amount of output.
Ex.

```
def execute_some_command(cmd="arbitrary_exe"):
    """ Execute some command using subprocess.call()"""
    #  open/create temportary file for stdout    
    tmp_out=file('.tmp','w+')

    #  Run command, pushing stdout to tmp_out file handle
    retcode = subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=tmp_out, shell=True)

    if retcode != 0:
        # do something useful (like bailout) based on the OS return code
        print "FAILED"

    #  Flush any queued data
    tmp_out.flush()
    #  Jump to the beginning
    tmp_out.seek(0)
    #  Parse output
    for line in tmp_out.readlines():
        # do something useful with output

    # cleanup 
    tmp_out.close()
    os.remove(_out.name)
return
```

Check out the methods on the python [file](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects) object for how to process the your stdout data from ***_out*** file handle.

Good hunting.